# Enviar un form si una condicion es verdadera

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo esta form que pide al usuario que de 4 numeros distintos del 0 al 9, pero necesito que de un mensaje de error cuando no pone ningun numero o repite alguno

```
<form action="/play" method="post" style="margin-top: 50px;" id="abcd">
    <input id="a" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="a" type="number" min="0" max="9" style="width: 7%"> </form>
```

Necesito que solamente se pueda enviar cuando esta funcion devuelve verdadero, como puedo hacer?

```
function validate(){

            var a;
            var b;
            var c;
            var d;
            a =document.getElementById('a').value;
            b=document.getElementById('b').value;
            c=document.getElementById('c').value;
            d=document.getElementById('d').value;

            if ( a ==="" || b==="" || c ==="" || d==="" ) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You must provide 4 numbers";
                return false;
            }
            else if ( a === b || a === c || a === d || b === c || b === d || c === d){
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Each digit can appear at most once.";
                return false;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los detalles que encontraras es que en JavaScript el `replace` solo quita una ocurrencia (la primera [mira aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)); ahora con [expresiones regulares](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-string-javascript/) puedes quitar las que existan, sin embargo como es un dato dinámico (hoy día) ignoro como sería.

Lo primero es que a tu `form` le agreges `onsumbit` mediante el cual *controlaras* si se envía o no tu formulario en base a el 'true' o `false` de una función que hay que colocar alli. Tu `form` quedaria (a mi sugerencia) de la siguiente forma:

```
<form [lo que a tu consideración debe llevar] onsubmit="return miFuncionValidacion()">
<!-- aqui tu código -->
</form>
```

Ahora bien `miFuncionValidacion` debe ser (en estructura similar):

```
function miFuncionValidacion() {

   /* Todo tu proceso para determinar devolver true o false */

   return [segun corresponda serà true o false];

}
```

Ahora para las condiciones que deseas; tomando tu código y observando estas usando solo JavaScript:

```
function miFuncionValidacion(){
   /* En una sola variable ponemos todo */
   var cadenaGeneral = document.getElementById('a').value +document.getElementById('b').value +document.getElementById('c').value +document.getElementById('d').value

   /* A continuación asumo que cada input solo permite y solo número, no diez, once, mil, etc. */
   /* Como son 4 numero su longitud debe ser igual a 4 :D */
   if (cadenaGenera.length!=4) /* Aqui le puedes poner sea igual, menor... */
   {
      return false;
   }
   else {
      /* Verificamos que lo contenido en "a" no se repita */
      /* Para esto usaremos split usando como separador lo contenido en "a"
         y join poniendo para "separar" cadena vacia y verificamos su longitud sea 3 */
      if ((cadenaGeneral.split(document.getElementById('a').value)).join("").length!=3)
      {
         return false;
      } else if ((cadenaGeneral.split(document.getElementById('b').value)).join("").length!=3)
      {
         return false;
      } /* Así para los otro 2 */
      /* finalmente */
      else {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
         return true; // Todo bien
      }
   }


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Muy clara la explicacion :D

Answer (score 0):

primero el form debes entregarle un boton tipo submit y capturar el evento onsubmit y asignarle tu funcion validate:

```
<form action="/play" method="post" style="margin-top: 50px;" id="abcd" onsubmit="validate">
    <input id="a" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="a" type="number" min="0" max="9" style="width: 7%"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```